# Possible to get text between two specific Regular Expression Matches?

Tags: javascript, regex

The text I have to parse is like this:

```
var textToParse = "INTRO

1.  MORE INTRO

2.  THINGS

3.  CONTENTS.   The 200 teststs.  The 300 test. 

4.  REF.  jytjndga.

5.  COLORING BOOK.  The 400 teststs.  The 500 test. 

WETRJEWO /EWRGGWE RE

100.
FUN STUFF

101.
RTHRT QWERATGER

A.  WSHNJDBRTH ARGSERTHERTHB

B. aqhretgwaefawef

C. trtrrttrtrtr

101.1
loads
   .2
thinking of loading
   .3
Loading 
   .4
unloading
   .5
reloading
   .6 
deloading
   .7
reREloading
   .8
done loading
   .9
not loading
   .10
fish

200.
PROCEDURES

201.
PROCEDURES 1

202.
PROCEDURES 2

A.  hear about procedure 203.

B.  think about procedure 203.

C.  eat cookie

D.  procrastinate

E.  sleep.

203.
PROCEDURES 3

203.1
A.  Trim Lawn

203.
PROCEDURES 3 (CONT’D)

203.1
B.  Clean stuff

C.  Finsih cleaning

204.
PROCEDURES 4

204.1
A.  wax on.

B.  Wax off

C.  crane kick

D.  Don't sweep the leg

E.  Sweep leg anyway

204.
PROCEDURES 4 (CONT’D)

204.1
F.  Finish procedure

205.
LAUNDRY DAY";
```

I run this regex to all of the main section headers (as well as some that aren't):

```
var sectionHeadersRegex = /^\s*\d{3}\.?(\s|$)/;
```

So my problem is this: I want to get all the text between two of the matches.

For example, I want to get all the text between match[1] ('101.') and match[5] ('203.').

So the Text would be:

```
var desireText = "RTHRT QWERATGER

A.  WSHNJDBRTH ARGSERTHERTHB

B. aqhretgwaefawef

C. trtrrttrtrtr

101.1
loads
   .2
thinking of loading
   .3
Loading 
   .4
unloading
   .5
reloading
   .6 
deloading
   .7
reREloading
   .8
done loading
   .9
not loading
   .10
fish

200.
PROCEDURES

201.
PROCEDURES 1

202.
PROCEDURES 2

A.  hear about procedure 203.

B.  think about procedure

C.  eat cookie

D.  procrastinate

E.  sleep.
";
```

I know there is extra whitespace that is included in the beginning of the matches and I know one answer is going to be that I can use the extra whitespace to make it so that if I do a regex like so:

```
var newRegexToGetTextBetweenMatchesOneandFive = new RegExp(' + match[1] + '([^~]+?)' + match[5] + '');
```

But I can't rely on the whitespace that prefixes the header number to prevent false matches.

Even if I could, the goal is to basically be able to say "get all the text between the second match and the sixth match" and not "get all the text between '101.' and ''203.".

Thanks for the help, and if I can clarify anything just let me know.

**EDIT:**

@Dawg sorry for being confusing. I think this example will clear things up.
@Wiktor your answer seems to be going about getting the text the same way.

I modified the text that needs to be parsed slightly so I can show the issue with the way you have it done.

```
var str = 'var textToParse = "INTRO\n\n1.  MORE INTRO\n\n2.  THINGS\n\n3.  CONTENTS.   The 200 teststs.  The 300 test. \n\n4.  REF.  jytjndga.\n\n5.  COLORING BOOK.  The 400 teststs.  The 500 test. \n\nWETRJEWO /EWRGGWE RE\n\n100.\nFUN STUFF\n\n101.\nRTHRT QWERATGER\n\nA.  WSHNJDBRTH ARGSERTHERTHB\n\nB. aqhretgwaefawef\n\nC. trtrrttrtrtr\n\n101.1\nloads\n   .2\nthinking of loading\n   .3\nLoading \n   .4\nunloading\n   .5\nreloading\n   .6 \ndeloading\n   .7\nreREloading\n   .8\ndone loading\n   .9\nnot loading\n   .10\nfish\n\n200.\nPROCEDURES\n\n201.\nPROCEDURES 1\n\n202.\nPROCEDURES 2\n\nA.  hear about procedure 203.\n\nB.  think about procedure 203.\n\nC.  eat cookie\n\nD.  procrastinate\n\nE.  sleep.\n\n203.\n THIS SHOULD BE CAPTURED\n\n203.\nPROCEDURES 3\n\n203.1\nA.  Trim Lawn\n\n203.\nPROCEDURES 3 (CONT’D)\n\n203.1\nB.  Clean stuff\n\nC.  Finsih cleaning\n\n204.\nPROCEDURES 4\n\n204.1\nA.  wax on.\n\nB.  Wax off\n\nC.  crane kick\n\nD.  Don\'t sweep the leg\n\nE.  Sweep leg anyway\n\n204.\nPROCEDURES 4 (CONT’D)\n\n204.1\nF.  Finish procedure\n\n205.\nLAUNDRY DAY";';
```

I modified part of it from:

```
'sleep.\n\n203.\nPROCEDURES'
```

to:

```
'sleep.\n\n203.\n THIS SHOULD BE CAPTURED\n\n203.\nPROCEDURES'
```

So now the closing match is match[6] instead of match[5].

So it can't just be a regex that has the text of the two matches in it as the start and end of the desired text.

**It needs to be all the text between the LOCATION of match[1] to the LOCATION of match[6].**

I wish I had thought of explaining it like that from the start. I think that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total revamp of my former anwer since the question was edited.

You need to get a substring between some matches of the following regex:

```
var re = /^\s*\b\d{3}\.?(?:\s|$)/gm;
```

Then, when you get your `str` ready, you can define an array for the indices of the matches:

```
var indices = [];
```

Then, iterate through all the matches with `RegExp.exec()`:

```
while((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
   indices.push({ start: m.index, end: m.index+m[0].length});
}
```

Note how the start and end positions are obtained: start position can be got from `MatchObject.index` property, and the end index is a sum total of the index and the match value (`m[0]`) length.

Next, you should get the text you need using the indices with `string.substring` method (see the `1` and `6` indices passed):

```
va0r newRegexToGetTextBetweenMatchesOneandFive = str.substring(indices[1].end, indices[6].start);
```

The first `indices[1]` property used is `end` (as we need to get text from the end of the first match, and the second `indices[6]` property is `start` as we need the substring up to the 6th match.

The whole demo is below.

```js
var re = /^\s*\b\d{3}\.?(?:\s|$)/gm; 
var str = 'var textToParse = "INTRO\n\n1.  MORE INTRO\n\n2.  THINGS\n\n3.  CONTENTS.   The 200 teststs.  The 300 test. \n\n4.  REF.  jytjndga.\n\n5.  COLORING BOOK.  The 400 teststs.  The 500 test. \n\nWETRJEWO /EWRGGWE RE\n\n100.\nFUN STUFF\n\n101.\nRTHRT QWERATGER\n\nA.  WSHNJDBRTH ARGSERTHERTHB\n\nB. aqhretgwaefawef\n\nC. trtrrttrtrtr\n\n101.1\nloads\n   .2\nthinking of loading\n   .3\nLoading \n   .4\nunloading\n   .5\nreloading\n   .6 \ndeloading\n   .7\nreREloading\n   .8\ndone loading\n   .9\nnot loading\n   .10\nfish\n\n200.\nPROCEDURES\n\n201.\nPROCEDURES 1\n\n202.\nPROCEDURES 2\n\nA.  hear about procedure 203.\n\nB.  think about procedure 203.\n\nC.  eat cookie\n\nD.  procrastinate\n\nE.  sleep.\n\n203.\n THIS SHOULD BE CAPTURED\n\n203.\nPROCEDURES 3\n\n203.1\nA.  Trim Lawn\n\n203.\nPROCEDURES 3 (CONT’D)\n\n203.1\nB.  Clean stuff\n\nC.  Finsih cleaning\n\n204.\nPROCEDURES 4\n\n204.1\nA.  wax on.\n\nB.  Wax off\n\nC.  crane kick\n\nD.  Don\'t sweep the leg\n\nE.  Sweep leg anyway\n\n204.\nPROCEDURES 4 (CONT’D)\n\n204.1\nF.  Finish procedure\n\n205.\nLAUNDRY DAY";';
var indices = [];
while((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
   indices.push({ start: m.index, end: m.index+m[0].length});
}
var newRegexToGetTextBetweenMatchesOneandFive = str.substring(indices[1].end, indices[6].start); 
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + newRegexToGetTextBetweenMatchesOneandFive + "</pre>";
```

Comment: That is still not really what I am talking about. My edit should help explain it better.

Comment: Fair enough. Pizza always comes first haha.

Comment: Ok, looks like you just want to split the string and get the required splits joined, right?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by that.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks!